# Can I copy SD cards using an iPod touch?

Tags: usb, sd-card

I'd like to backup photos taken on my dSLR camera on SD cards. Can I use a USB adapter to copy an SD card into the iPod's local memory, then attach a different SD card and copy the files to that?

Answer (score 2):

Probably not, as the [Apple iPad Camera Connection Kit](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4101#) is officially not supported on iPhone or iPod touch; and that would just give you the physical connection of your SD card to the iPod touch.

To have direct access to the file-system of your SD-card you need a jailbreak.
There is a slight chance you may get the [Apple iPad Camera Connection Kit](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4101#) working on a jailbroken iPod touch:

Check out [iConnectionKit](http://iconnectionkit.blogspot.com/) and [this YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HvWEDNh4vvs).

> Camera Connection Kit on iPhone / iPod Touch (upcoming JB tweak)
>
> PROJECT STATUS = ALPHA
>
> Top 5 contributors will be granted early beta access on 2nd of April 2012.
>
> SUPPORTED DEVICES - iOS 5.0.1
>
> - iPod Touch 4G - [Tested & Working] - Watch the demonstration videos.
> - iPod Touch 3G - [Possible] Contribute any amount to help us afford the device and enable the Camera Connection Kit
> - iPhone 3GS - [Possible] Contribute any amount to help us afford the device and enable the Camera Connection Kit
> - iPhone 4S - [Possible] Contribute any amount to help us afford the device and enable the Camera Connection Kit
> - iPhone 4 - [Possible] Contribute any amount to help us afford the device and enable the Camera Connection Kit
>
> JB required.

Answer (score 0):

I bought a "hitch" a while back & this lets you transfer data from one usb device to another without anything else needed.  I have used usb card readers plugged into one end & various other usb devices plugged into the other & it has always worked.  Hope this helps.